# Python: Open file with default application and capture 'save event'

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, file-io

I would like to know if it's possible to **capture** the save method over a file opened through python.

Let's supose I have an xls file that I've opened with:

```
import os, subprocess

filepath = '/home/myuser/myFile.xls'
subprocess.call(('xdg-open', filepath))
```

- Would be possible to capture the '*close event*' on the opened file ?
- Would be possible to capture the '*save event*' on the opened file ?
- Would be possible to do anything like that on a file maped in memory with **mmap** ?

I'm trying to have a compressed folder in a USB and I'd like to develop a custom Python app that can show the files/folder in the compressed file without interacting directly with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a portable way to do that. But from you code looks like you are working on linux. On linux there is inotify which can give you notification about usage of files. It's usable from python via [pyinotify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinotify). Details about the events you can listen for are found in the [manpage for inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

You can monitor for an IN_CLOSE_WRITE event on the file to catch a "save" operation in the application. Depending on the application it might not be very reliable though. For example the application could open the file for writing when loading the file initially. Or the application might not really save over the existing file, but to a different temporary file and use a move operation to replace the old file.

These are also fixable by listening for actual changes to the file (IN_MODIFY) or changes to the directory containing the file (inotify on the directory instead of the file and looking at the filename). But there might be other situations where your script might get confused from just reading these events (auto save for example).

So you should carefully consider if you can get this reliable enough that it really is a feature you users can depend on, or if the users are better of to have this explicitly. The traditional unix way is to just wait for the editing application to terminate. But with modern editors that do open multiple files using the same process (often reusing an already running process even when started with a file name) this no longer is a universal solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The information is worthy. I'm trying to have a compressed folder using python, and I'm wondering how can I edit/view the compressed files without compressing/uncompressing all the files to interact with them. I'd like to do all of that on Python, maybe I should change to C++. I will play with this info to achieve this in Linux

Comment: Going more into complex solutions you could make it a real directory by using fuse and decompressing on first access. You really never know when files depend on other files to be opened correctly (think html files).